# adding array's contents to a JFrame, add JPanel, add a JScroll

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
String[] option = {"Adlawan", "Angeles", "Arreza", "Benenoso", "Bermas",
                   "Brebante", "Cabaylo", "C. Cainglet", "O. Cainglet",
                   "Calunsag", "Cameros", "Casanaan", "Catulong", "Chicote",
                   "Dela Paz", "Ea", "Echavez"};

int choose = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "WHICH EMPLOYEE'S DATA WOULD YOU
             LIKE TO RESET?", "Click to Choose Type of Leave Credits",
             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
             null, option, option[16]);
```

Its running perfectly, the only problem I have is that the `JOptionPane` (with the names to choose) does not fit the screen, how can I add the names into a frame or a panel and put a `JScroll` into it so it would fit the screen.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a list to display options, for example:

```
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestOptions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] options = { "Adlawan", "Angeles", "Arreza", "Benenoso",
                "Bermas", "Brebante", "Cabaylo", "C. Cainglet", "O. Cainglet",
                "Calunsag", "Cameros", "Casanaan", "Catulong", "Chicote",
                "Dela Paz", "Ea", "Echavez" };

        JList list = new JList(options);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, scrollPane,
                "Select employee", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list.getSelectedValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  In my program each name in the list has a different and unique method attached to it, for example if i choose/click "Adlawan" a password box would appear, and when if I choose/click "Angeles" an JOptionPane.showInputDialog Box would appear, how would i integrate those method by only selecting the name on the list and clicking OK_OPtion, thanks....

Comment: @AlexBernardo in your current implementation, how do you attach these unique methods?

Comment: @AlexBernardo Not sure I understand your question. In the sample above, `list.getSelectedValue()` returns the selected name. You can use it to fire a proper method.

Comment: I attached my unique methods to those name by calling them from subclass.

Comment: if (option == 0) {adlawanSection adlawan = new adlawanSection(); adlawan.adlawan2()} end of codes.  (adlawanSection is my subclass) (adlawan is my object) and (adlawan2 is the method from my subclass) and under the method adlawan2 is a simple code JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mrs. Adlawan is from finance section:);

Comment: @AlexBernardo You could do the same with list selection, for example: `if ("Adlawan".equals(list.getSelectedValue())){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mrs. Adlawan is from finance section:");}`

Comment: Sir, if its not much of a favor can ask one more question?  I've already finished my application and I've also converted my code into a runnable jar file and convert it to a .exe.  My question is how can i configure my application so i can use it in our local area network, say for example, i can use one of our station to encode or update some data then the data will be save in our server.  Can you give me a tip on how to achieve this goal.  Thanks and more power.

Comment: @AlexBernardo there are many possible ways to implement such scenario. However, without details it is hard to suggest a concrete one.

Comment: Sir are you referring to the code i used when you say "details"?  Or maybe you are referring to the ambiguity of my question.  I'll try to be detailed as much as i can.  My completed program allow a user to encode data(number of costumer per day) and is capable of tabulating the result monthly.  The program work just fine, but the problem is, every time i encode data, those data are written and save on to the hard disk of the computer where i install my program.

Comment: The concept of my program is to deploy it to out network so all the station connected to the network can use the application, the goal i wanted to achieved is that, every time a person uses the application and encode data from any of our computer station, data encode will be save to our server's hard disk and not on to the hard disk of the computer station where the user is encoding the data.  How do i do this?  To allow all our station to serve as a encoding station but all data are passed to the server's hard disk.  I am currently studying TCP/IP networking, am i in the right path? thanks!

Comment: @AlexBernardo Serving a file using sockets is straightforward. However, how complex is this file sharing? What kind of security is applied? Is there a role based access restrictions to files? May there be several users collaborating on the same data? How simultaneous writes should be handled? What happens when file gets updated while other users view it? And there are many other fundamental questions. Plain FTP can be a solution if all you need is file sharing between applications. For more complex scenarios, you may require a more sophisticated logic on the server.